# What is the difference between the = operator and the reserved word by when assigning a remeber in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to know the difference between:

```kotlin
var textFieldState = remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
```

and

```kotlin
var textFieldState by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
```

Is there any advantage over the other?

Comment: `by` in this context is a kotlin property delegate.  Any class that implements the operarator fun  `operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): T` can use this syntax.  Using `=` will eagerly assign the variable, the `by` will delegate to the Return types operator function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any advantage over the other?

The first really should be a `val` and not a `var`. Otherwise, they are equivalent. Or, to quote [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables):

> There are three ways to declare a MutableState object in a composable:

> - `val mutableState = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }`
> - `var value by remember { mutableStateOf(default) }`
> - `val (value, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }`

> These declarations are equivalent, and are provided as syntax sugar for different uses of state. You should pick the one that produces the easiest-to-read code in the composable you're writing.

In those three:

- In the first, `mutableState` holds a `MutableState`, and you use `.value` and `.value=` to manipulate the contents
- In the second, `value` holds a `MutableState`, but the `by` syntax tells the compiler to treat it as a [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html), so we can pretend that `value` just holds the underlying data
- In the third, a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html) gives you getter and setter references to manipulate the content in the underlying `MutableState`

Answer (score 1):

The `by` in this context is a kotlin property delegate.  Any class that implements the operator fun  `operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): T` can use this syntax.  Using `=` will eagerly assign the variable (importantly without delegation), the `by` will delegate to the operator function.  The `remember` in this case is just a shortcut function to creating the Remember delgate that wraps the value you are creating inside the `{ ... }` block.

A typical example is the kotlin `Lazy<T>` class : `val myValue : Int by lazy { 1 }`.  If used with the `by` operator you will return the `Int` value, if used with `=` it will return `Lazy<Int>` as you have not used delegation.

It is also worth noting that delgates can be setters as well by using this operator fun : `operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: T)`.